# Array of Structs - Hash Table

Tags: c, pointers, hash, struct, malloc

I have a problem with this struct and I don't understand why doesn't work. I create a struct with 3 values and I want array with this SIZE = 100. But I'm confused with the malloc and how it works in this scenario.

```
#define SIZE 100

typedef struct entry {
    long id;
    int r1;
    int r2;
    int r3;
};

typedef struct entry * THash; //[SIZE];

THash init ()
{
    int i;
    THash  t = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(struct entry));

for(i = 0; i<SIZE; i++){
    t[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
    t[i].id = -1;
    t[i].r1 = -1;
    t[i].r2 = -1;
    t[i].r3 = -1;

}
return t;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to allocate memory twice. The first malloc is enough. It allocates memory for all the 100 structs. You can use them directly inside the loop. Also rmember to free the memory after use. It is generally a good practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you are doing in your current program is, as Ajay pointed out in a comment, allocating the memory twice.
Let's analyze the two different mallocs in your code to see what they are doing better so you can understand what's happening :)
The first malloc, that is:

```
THash  t = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(struct entry));
```

is taking the dimensions of your structure using the amazing (and life saving) C function `sizeof` and allocating the space needed by the structure 100 times. That is it is taking a pointer in the memory and allocating the memory from that point forward until the amount needed by 100 structures is reached. It is then storing the pointer in t making it, effectively, an array.

You can then simply access your array and its content by using t[0], t[1] etc, as if it was a simple array.

What you are doing with your second `malloc`, that is

```
t[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
```

is reallocating some space that you have already allocated and trying to assign a pointer to the newly allocated region to the pointer to the structure (this is quite messy, I know) in fact, if you try to compile your code you'll get the following error and the function will not compile:

```
error: assigning to 'struct entry' from incompatible type 'void *'
    t[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct entry));
         ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

So, in order to make the function work, you simply need to remove the second malloc. I hope I made myself enough clear to what the function is doing in your situation but feel free to ask more question if you need further explanations

Comment: Thanks for this amazing answer!! Last question: If I want use "->" instead "." in t[i].id, what changes do I need to make?

Comment: You are very welcome! I'm afraid my memory is failing on me and I can't help you with that, but I remember it not being too hard, a couple of google searches and you should be all set!